# Is dividing a term in a complex matrix has the same effect as multiplying a global phase?

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers

Suppose I have the following matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a+bi & c+di\\
e+fi & j+hi
\end{bmatrix}
$$
If I divide each entry by $a+bi$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \frac{c+di}{a+bi}\\
\frac{e+fi}{a+bi} & \frac{j+hi}{a+bi}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Does this operation have the same effect as multiplying a phase $e^{i\alpha}$ to  the original matrix? Thanks!

Comment: If your "phase" requires $\alpha$ to be real, generally no, this operation will not have the same effect as multiplying by a phase. The division has the effect of adjusting the matrix entries by both the phase and magnitude of $a+bi$. If you are only adjusting by the phase, you would be likely to be left with not a $1$ in the first row, first column entry, but just the real number $|a+bi|$ there. And you would not be dividing by $a+bi$ but simply a phase associated with an angle of $a+bi$.